# Reset values of a select box, separate button or inside select?

Tags: forms, selection, reset

I have a filter form with two select boxes to filter results. I've a red button to reset search and view all results, but I'm not sure if I should add "All" at the beginning of each select box?

What are your opinions and why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If i understand issue correctly you want to select multiple states to filter by. I would probably approach it like this, have a reset button within a dropdown to clear all selected tick boxes:

http://z2l32f.axshare.com/#g=1&p=home&c=1

and sorry for ghetto prototype.